# Polymorphism table divided on 3 controllers

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

I am building an application where you can write reviews on a `company` their profile. This is normally a one to many relation, but in the application, you can also write reviews on an `apartment` page and `arrangements` page. So I have 3 different pages to add the review functionality. Obviously, the user can edit and delete reviews too.

the `reviews` table is polymorphic. So you have a field with `reviewable_type` and `reviewable_id`

Now I was thinking to make a `ReviewController` to reduce code duplication. The problem I am facing right now is that I need to display the reviews on these 3 different pages, but I don't want to include the same code in every controller (`ApartmentController`, `ArrangementController`, `CompanyController`).

What's the best way to achieve this solution without duplicating to much code.

I was thinking to put a special class outside the MVC pattern, but I want to keep is as close to the MVC pattern.

Also, I thought of putting another method in the 3 controllers, but then again there's going to be code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the traits to achieve this.

Make a new trait `ReviewTrait` and put the code in it and use in all the controllers.

You can find more traits here [Link](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/traits-in-laravel-5db8beffbcc3).

Answer (score 0):

Create a modal function inside the company modal lets called it Reviews, which takes the review type as a parameter.

Now call the modal function Reviews with review type in the ApartmentController,  ArrangementController, CompanyController.